# text mining in R

Tags: r, text-mining

I would like to create a TDM from a text with specific sentences (two or more words combined) instead of single words. The sentences could be for example `"climate change"`, `"global worming"`, `"lad use"`, etc. The examples I have seen are all with single words.

```
tabela = DocumentTermMatrix(textolimpo,
         list(dictionary = c("climate change","global worming","land use")))
```

I appreciate if someone could help me.

Cheers.

Rafael

Answer (score 2):

I recommend `quanteda`:

```
library(quanteda)
textolimpo <- c("This climate change concerns me. This climate changes", "Wormed: global worming increased")
(dfm <- dfm(textolimpo, 
           ngrams=2L,
           dictionary = list(climate="climate_change",
                             warm="global_worming"), 
           valuetype = "regex"))
# 2 x 2 sparse Matrix of class "dfmSparse"
#        features
# docs    climate warm
#   text1       2    0
#   text2       0    1
(dfm <- dfm(textolimpo, 
            ngrams=2L, 
            thesaurus = list(climate="climate_change",
                             warm="global_worming"), 
            valuetype = "regex"))
# 2 x 8 sparse Matrix of class "dfmSparse"
#       this_climate change_concerns concerns_me me_this wormed_global worming_increased CLIMATE WARM
# text1            2               1           1       1             0                 0       2    0
# text2            0               0           0       0             1                 1       0    1
```

Comment: is global worming what happened in Tremors?